# Testing STDIN in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, stdin

I'm currently trying to test a basic method that receives some input from the user (gets) and outputs it (puts). After a bit of research I found a good way to test the standard output stream which is the below:

```
def capture_standard_output(&block)
  original_stream = $stdout
  $stdout = mock = StringIO.new
  yield
  mock.string.chomp
ensure
  $stdout = original_stream
end
```

The method I'm testing is the one below, output and input refer to ivars which I initialize in the beginning and point to the equivalent $stdout & $stdin:

```
def ask_for_mark
  ouput.puts 'What shall I call you today?'
  answer = input.gets.chomp.capitalize
  answer
end
```

Now I've seen some solutions for STDIN but haven't really understood any of them and I definitely don't want to copy & paste. The only one I got to "work" is the one below, but it's not really working since when I run rspec it pauses and waits for input and by simply pressing enter, it passes:

```
  it "takes user's name and returns it" do
    output = capture_standard_output { game.ask_for_name }
    expect(output).to eq "What shall I call you today?"
    game.input.stub(:gets) { 'joe' }
    expect(game.ask_for_name).to eq 'Joe'
  end
```

What would be a good way to test STDIN? I've been staring at a screen for most of the day (not good, I know) so a fresh perspective and some help would be greatly appreciated :-)

#### Update

For anyone facing similar issues, I followed different (simpler) approaches. First, I would separate the IO operations in their own methods.

In the case of input, in the tests it can be pre-populated with the desired data so when the `gets` message is send, it will return that data which are separated by the newline character `\n` like so:

```
input = StringIO.new("one\ntwo\n")
=> #<StringIO:0x007f88152f3510>
input.gets
=> "one\n"
input.gets
=> "two\n"
input.gets
=> nil
```

This helps with keep the internals of the method under test, private without coupling the tests to the implementation details.

Another approach is to simply use polymorphism and pass in a Fake or a Spy object that conforms to the same api but instead of making a call to `stdin` or `stdout`, it returns canned data instead or in the case of the Spy, it registers the call.

```
class SpyIO
  def initialize
    was_called? = false
  end
  ...
  def ask_for_name
    # call to stdout would normally take place
    was_called? = true
  end
  ...
end

class FakeIO
  def initialize(data = [some, data])
    @data = data
  end

  def get_user_input
    # call to stdin would normally happen
    @data.shift
  end
  ...
end
```

There's tradeoffs in each approach but I thought I'd put these here in case anyone was having similar issues or considering options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply *stub STDIN*:

```
it "takes user's name and returns it" do
  output = capture_standard_output { game.ask_for_name }
  expect(output).to eq "What shall I call you today?"
  allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets) { 'joe' }
  expect(game.ask_for_name).to eq 'Joe'
end
```

Actually, you can do the same with `STDOUT`, without needing to change `$stdout`:

```
it "takes user's name and returns it" do
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("What shall I call you today?")
  allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets) { 'joe' }
  expect(game.ask_for_name).to eq 'Joe'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Well I can't really be sure, but one problem I had (still have) when working with $stdin / $stdout / StringIO is making sure to run #rewind on them. Are you doing that?

```
input = StringIO.new
input.puts "joe"
input.rewind
input.gets #=> "joe\n"
```