# Redirect $stdin to string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stdin

I'm writing a unit test for my class which reads inputs from stdin.  In the unit tests, I'm hoping I can redirect the stdin stream to a string.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your literal question: unlike the constant `STDIN`, `$stdin` is just a global variable, you can replace it with another IO object:

```
require 'stringio'
$stdin = StringIO.new("foo\nbar")
2.times { puts gets }
# => foo
# => bar
```

But it is probably a better idea to use a proper mocking framework instead, for example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349863/testing-stdin-in-ruby).